# Turkish characters are coming as question mark in TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf

I have added a new font "open-sans" to tcpdf, but when I will use open sans as font, all Turkish characters are coming as question mark in tcpdf. Please help me on this.

Comment: Fonts are always a challenge in TCPDF. There are a lot of questions similar to yours on SO. One thing you can do is modify the code in this snippet to get an idea of which characters are available in the currently loaded font: http://pastebin.com/fDJLSsP4